# How do I check which cards I’ve collected?

Tags: the-sexy-brutale

There are 52 playing cards hidden as collectibles throughout *The Sexy Brutale*. (7 of hearts, king of diamonds, etc).

While cards are initially identified by name when picked up, the progress menu only shows the total number of cards collected (50/52). This makes it seemingly impossible to tell which cards are missing.

**Is there a way to check which cards I’ve collected so far?**

Answer (score 4):

**You can on PC, but not ingame!**

To check which card you have collected you have to look in your save file. Open it in a text editor (notepad is fine) and search for text with the format card_[suit]_[value]. You will find the cards that you have found ingame.

The suit-value are

- d: Diamond
- h: Heart
- c: Clubs
- s: Spades

And value is 2-10 or j, q, k, a.

For a guide see [Hülk27's guide on steam http://steamcommunity.com/sharedfiles/filedetails/?id=953863195](http://steamcommunity.com/sharedfiles/filedetails/?id=953863195)

Comment: Ohh, so Steam has a different save file location than non-Steam versions, *and* it doesn't have *The Sexy Brutale* in the path at all! So *that's* why I couldn't find it.